# Ошибка при использовании SoapClient в PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

Впервые столкнулся с использованием SOAP протокола, вроде всё ясно, но не могу разобраться с ошибкой. Вот сама ошибка:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [s:Client] Value cannot be null. Parameter name: parameters in /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php:7 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php(7): SoapClient->__soapCall('GetAdditionalCo...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php on line 7

А вот сам код:

```
$params = array('agentUid' => '9B724100-83B5-4EA0-9F55-452C07D131AE');
$client = new SoapClient("https://ti.alfastrah.ru/TIService/InsuranceAlfaService.svc?wsdl");
$result = S$client->__soapCall('GetAdditionalConditions', $params);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: а  xml покажите?

Comment: Кажется приходит кривой ответ

Comment: @Voltenko, дополнения к вопросу (xml  в данном случае) должно быть в самом вопросе.